# Implement custom logic on value of a custom component in template driven forms

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to create a survey form purely from JSON data. So, I chose template-driven approach. Now the issue is that I have a custom component for dropdown. I want to change it's selected score value according to custom weightage logic. I want to achieve something like this in a custom directive:

```
processInput(value: any) {
       return value * 500;
   }

   @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
   ngModelChange(value: any) {
       this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.processInput(value));
   }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Reactive forms are a much better choice for this scenario..

Comment: @MikeOne: I agree, but the use case is of generating different surveys based on JSON. As such, I can't have a fixed form group definition.